# Adding links to every record with Spring REST + MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, spring-mvc, hateoas

I'm trying to add links to every record in my databse, as I am trying to implement the HATEOAS concept. However, I have been experiencing some trouble with this. I tried following this guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/. But with no success. How and where should I write the code for adding links? Because it doesn't seem to work when I try to write it in my controller method because withSelfRel() is undefined.

Basically I'm trying to add a link to every account made in my database.

```
    //Create account 
@RequestMapping(value="/accounts", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public ResponseEntity<?> accountInsert(@RequestBody Account account) {
    account = new Account(account.getFirstName(), account.getLastName(), account.getEmail(), account.getPassword(), account.getBirthDate(), account.getActivities(), account.getFriends());
    accountRepository.save(account);
    //account.add(linkTo(methodOn(AccountController.class, accountInsert(account)).withSelfRel()));   /// HERE IS MY TRY
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setLocation(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().build().toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess you have written right code, you can simply add url in `@RequestMapping`.  which error you are getting

Comment: "The method withSelfRel() is undefined for the type AccountController". It doesn't recognize the method. Are you sure the code is right? Because I think methodOn requires (class, String) and I have inserted (class, account) which is an object.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use method inside the same one
Try this :-

```
Link self=linkTo(AccountController.class).slash(account.getId()).withSelfRel();
```

Or you can refer from given [link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=tutorial.rest.mvc.BlogController)

Comment: {
  "timestamp": "2016-04-25T09:02:20.986+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException",
  "message": "Failed to instantiate org.springframework.hateoas.UriTemplate using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments ",
  "path": "/accounts"
}

Comment: Do I need to add a constructor somewhere?

Comment: there is no need to write constructor but I guess first you go through that link you will get whatever you want to implement

Comment: When I implement "extends ResourceSupport" in my class file I get that error. I have to do that so I can use the add() and link methods. But then I get that error when I try to get all records in my database..

Comment: @BananaBackend did you find a solution to this ?